# number of chars in a string with scanf() and switch-statment

Tags: c, arrays, string, switch-statement, scanf

## What i'm trying to do

i'm trying to count the number of characters in a string. i try to save a string in an array `CH[100]`, then start a `switch-statement` to find how much the character `Q` is repeated...

## the Code

> 114.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 100
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* CH[SIZE];
    int alpha[26] = { 0 };
    unsigned int i = 0; 

    printf("name\n");
        scanf("%s", CH);
    while(i < SIZE){
        if(CH[i] != '\0')
        {   
            switch(CH[i])
            {
                case 'a':
                case 'A': ++alpha[0]; break;
                case 'b':
                case 'B': ++alpha[1]; break;
                case 'c':
                case 'C': ++alpha[1]; break;
                .           .           .   
                .           .           .
                .           .           .
                case 'y': 
                case 'Y': ++alpha[24]; break;
                case 'z': 
                case 'Z': ++alpha[25]; break;
            }//end switch
        }else{ break;}
    ++i;
    }//end while
    for(int j = 65; j < 91; ++j)
    {
        if(alpha[j- 65] != 0)
        printf("%s\t - %d times\n",(char) j,alpha[j- 65]);
    }
}
```

## Compilation and execution:

```
[ar.lnx@host Documents] $ gcc 114.c -o x
[ar.lnx@host Documents] $ ./x
donner le nom
anas
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[ar.lnx@host Documents] $
```

i can't understand what is the problem, can someone help me find what's happening here

Comment: Check the indexes! And use a better test string, e.g. `abc...z`. Btw: That is too error-prone; use the code to directly index into the array. And do not use all-uppercase for variables.

Comment: You use `%s` to print a character; use `%c` instead. (The `%s` expects a `char *`, which it dereferences. The ASCII value you pass as variadic argument isn't a valid address and probably dosn't have the right size.. Compile with warnings enabled to learn about format/argument mismatches.)

Comment: Note, you can get rid of the if inside the while by setting `len=strlen(CH);` and making the while a for loop `for(i=0; i<len; i++)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, change `%s` to `%c` in your `printf`.

Do

```
printf("%c\t - %d times\n",(char) j,alpha[j- 65]);
```

instead of

```
printf("%s\t - %d times\n",(char) j,alpha[j- 65]);
```

Your corrected code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 100
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char CH[SIZE];
    int alpha[26] = { 0 };
    unsigned int i = 0; 

    printf("name\n");
        scanf("%s", CH);
    while(i < SIZE){
        if(CH[i] != '\0')
        {   
            switch(CH[i])
            {
                case 'a':
                case 'A': ++alpha[0]; break;
                case 'b':
                case 'B': ++alpha[1]; break;
                case 'c':
                case 'C': ++alpha[1]; break;
                case 'y': 
                case 'Y': ++alpha[24]; break;
                case 'z': 
                case 'Z': ++alpha[25]; break;
            }//end switch
        }else{ break;}
    ++i;
    }//end while
    int j;
    for( j = 65; j < 91; ++j)
    {
        if(alpha[j- 65] != 0)
        printf("%c\t - %d times\n",(char) j,alpha[j- 65]);
    }
}
```

If you are having a doubt on the difference between `%c` and `%s`, check [this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-c-and-s-in-c-programming).

Comment: You should probably highlight this modification: `char CH[SIZE];` in your code vs `char * CH[SIZE];` in the OPs code. This should've been the cause for the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

The only mistake is while printing the count replace `%s` with `%c`
i.e change

```
printf("%s\t - %d times\n",(char) j,alpha[j- 65]);
```

to

```
printf("%c\t - %d times\n",(char) j,alpha[j- 65]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `printf` format:

```
printf("%s\t - %d times\n",(char) j,alpha[j- 65]);
```

Change it to this:

```
printf("%c\t - %d times\n",j,alpha[j- 65]);
```

The `char` cast is harmless but unnecessary.  The real problem is the `%s` which needs to be `%c`.